# Are these lines an error or info in Apache's error log?

Tags: apache

I have just looked at my error_logs for a particular site of mine which I haven't done in a while and in Apache's error_log i find hundreds of lines that have this same format:

```
[Mon Mar 16 19:20:03 2009] [error] [client xx.81.239.xxx] [Mon Mar 16 19:20:03 2009] [info] Executing "/home/get/public_html/fileReader.php" as UID 32596, GID 32599, referer: http://www.mysite.com/index.php
[Mon Mar 16 19:20:03 2009] [error] [client xx.3.27.xx] [Mon Mar 16 19:20:03 2009] [info] Executing "/home/get/public_html/fileReader.php" as UID 32596, GID 32599, referer: http://www.mysite.com/index.php
[Mon Mar 16 19:20:03 2009] [error] [client xx.202.191.xx] [Mon Mar 16 19:20:02 2009] [info] Executing "/home/get/public_html/fileReader.php" as UID 32596, GID 32599, referer: http://www.mysite.com/index.php
```

I have Googled and could not find anything on this. What does it mean? Is it even an error? If not, way record it?

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these log entries [originate](http://suphp.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.6.2-3/Application_8cpp-source.html#l00112) from [suPHP](http://www.google.com/search?q=suphp). they are info messages, not errors (the code says `logger.logInfo(...)`, *not* `logger.logError(...)`). you can suppress them by setting suPHP's `loglevel` [configuration option](http://www.suphp.org/DocumentationView.html?file=CONFIG) to "warn", "error", or "none".

Answer (score 0):

These entries might be some [custom error log format](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats).